# CommandButton: conditional oncomplete

Tags: visualforce, oncomplete

My command button inserts a new record into the page. When I integrate `oncomplete="formReset()"`, the page reloads and I can see the new record on the page.

```
function formReset(){window.location.href='/apex/pagename';}
```

With record creation, I also create an info message that the record has been created. But when there is an error, the page should not reload, as the error then would disappear. Therefore, I implemented a conditional oncomplete: `oncomplete="if(!hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR)){formReset()}"`

Although there is no error, the page does not reload anymore. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you using commandButton?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123222/check-for-error-messages-on-vf-pages

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4962/apex-variables-used-in-javascript-of-vf-is-not-getting-updated-with-latest-value